# find total width of text and break it after a limit fiddle jquery

Tags: jquery

This is a function to check the total characters width written in a div....if this width surpass a limit set, there is a break line....

**PROBLEM**
I need to check the width of a single line of the paragraph `testLine` but I cant apply the function `.textWidth()` to it...

How do I apply the function to it? to return the paragraph with break lines.

```js
//function
$.fn.textWidth = function(text, font) {
    if (!$.fn.textWidth.fakeEl) $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl = $('<span>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
    $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.text(text || this.val() || this.text()).css('font', font || this.css('font'));
    return $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.width();
};


//building
$('#inpt').on('input', function() {
var containerLmt="260";//pixels
var TotalCharsWidth=$(this).textWidth()
$('#inpt-width').html( TotalCharsWidth+ 'px');

 /*
//creating the paragraph 
 var words = $(this);
 var line = '';
 for(var n = 0; n <  words.length; n++) {
          var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';

 if (TotalCharsWidth > containerLmt && n > 0) { //problem

            line = words[n] + TotalCharsWidth + ' ';
        
}else {
            line = testLine;

          }

  }

   */




}).trigger('input');
```

```css
#inpt{border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="inpt" contenteditable>ddhhhd</div>
<div id="inpt-width"></div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what are you looking for: https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/VXdBeM?editors=1010

The function `textWidth` is working fine.
The problem is you call wrong function to get words. Should be `var words = $(this).html();` instead of `var words = $(this);`

```
//creating the paragraph 
var words = $(this).html();
var line = '';
for(var n = 0; n <  words.length; n++) {
    var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
    if (TotalCharsWidth > containerLmt && n > 0) { //problem
    console.log('123');
        line = words[n] + TotalCharsWidth + ' ';
    } else {
        line = testLine;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tested the results? it doesnt break the lines in the codeiopen

Comment: So you commend your problem. And I checked, I write console log for you. You need to do by your own and comeback if you have any problem.

Comment: yes definitely, I'm testing it, just I cant get what expected. here in this fiddle I have the main code https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gvq7m/205/, could you please chek it out? the thing is to break a new line once the line width have reached the maxWidth limit and start a new line....it doesnt seems to work in the main fiddle I attached here

Comment: the line I have problem is this `var TotalCharsWidth=testLine.textWidth() alert(TotalCharsWidth)` it doesnt show up the alert. this one has t replace to `var testWidth = metrics.width;` in the main code to make it work properly

Comment: Maybe this is something you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gvq7m/224/ `var TotalCharsWidth=$('#first_text').textWidth();` and please if you define jquery plugin, you need to define outside `for`.

Comment: well I got to the same result, the words start being witten one by one below and get a wierd behaviour using this function. `var TotalCharsWidth=$('#first_text').textWidth();` this function have to be applied to the line `testline` but it doesnt work

Comment: If you want to break the words, I suggest you use css https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break